# How to implement a continuous motion illusion in SVG?

Tags: animation, svg

Imagine a progress-bar like this one, which creates a sensation of motion towards the left:
[image: progress bar]
*Note: the thin bright-green line on top of the animation is a compression artifact.*

I am looking for a way to implement something similar, but in an arbitrary SVG path, such as this one:
[image: curve]

I am trying to understand what is really going on there, e.g.:

- Is it a gradient with many stops, and the stops keep moving?
- Are these many adjacent, skewed rectangles moving in unison?
- Is it one long sequence of skewed adjacent rectangles, with a "sliding window" moving along it?

How can such animations be conceptualized? And what would be the best practice to implement it using SVG primitives?

Comment: SVG is still somewhat slower/less supported than animated gifs. You sure you want to use it? In the end. when 99% of world will switch there will be new cool-er format.

Comment: Yes, because this is a part of an interface that leverages SVG features to fulfill its mission (i.e. hover effects, reaction to clicks, tooltips for some of its elements, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using a path twice:`#a` and `#b`. Both `#a` and `#b` have `stroke-dasharray: 1` but `#b` id offset `stroke-dashoffset: 1;`

I'm animating the `stroke-dashoffset` for both `#a` and `#b`.

```css
use {
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
}
#a {
  stroke: green;
  animation: dasha 5s linear infinite;
}
#b {
  stroke: DarkSeaGreen;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  animation: dashb 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dasha {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -54.66;
  }
}
@keyframes dashb {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -53.66;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' width="200"><title>gesture</title>
    <defs><path id="thePath"  fill="none" d='M4.59 6.89c.7-.71 1.4-1.35 1.71-1.22.5.2 0 1.03-.3 1.52-.25.42-2.86 3.89-2.86 6.31 0 1.28.48 2.34 1.34 2.98.75.56 1.74.73 2.64.46 1.07-.31 1.95-1.4 3.06-2.77 1.21-1.49 2.83-3.44 4.08-3.44 1.63 0 1.65 1.01 1.76 1.79-3.78.64-5.38 3.67-5.38 5.37 0 1.7 1.44 3.09 3.21 3.09 1.63 0 4.29-1.33 4.69-6.1h2.46'></path>
  </defs>
    <use id="a" xlink:href="#thePath" />
    <use id="b" xlink:href="#thePath" />
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

If you use css variables you can use only one animation:

```css
use {
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
}
#a {
  --offset:0;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dashoffset: 53.66;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}
#b {
  --offset:1;
  stroke: DarkSeaGreen;
  stroke-dashoffset: 54.66;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--offset)
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' width="200"><title>gesture</title>
    <defs><path id="thePath"  fill="none" d='M4.59 6.89c.7-.71 1.4-1.35 1.71-1.22.5.2 0 1.03-.3 1.52-.25.42-2.86 3.89-2.86 6.31 0 1.28.48 2.34 1.34 2.98.75.56 1.74.73 2.64.46 1.07-.31 1.95-1.4 3.06-2.77 1.21-1.49 2.83-3.44 4.08-3.44 1.63 0 1.65 1.01 1.76 1.79-3.78.64-5.38 3.67-5.38 5.37 0 1.7 1.44 3.09 3.21 3.09 1.63 0 4.29-1.33 4.69-6.1h2.46'></path>
  </defs>
    <use id="a" xlink:href="#thePath" />
    <use id="b" xlink:href="#thePath" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you provide some recommendations of tutorials and documentation one could process in order to get a better grasp of the fundamentals and synthesize such solutions independently? I managed to adapt the example to my situation, but it was mostly via trial and error, rather than a clear vision of what it is that I'm doing.

Comment: This book is a must: [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://www.amazon.com/Using-SVG-CSS3-HTML5-Graphics/dp/1491921978/ref=sr_1_fkmrnull_1?crid=7S0E0XQGEAJF&keywords=amelia+bellamy-royds&qid=1558019129&s=gateway&sprefix=amelia+bell%2Caps%2C318&sr=8-1-fkmrnull)

Answer (score 1):

Well one way of doing it is with an animated pattern. Something like this:

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="skewrect"  x="0%" y="0%" width="20%" height="100%" patternTransform="skewX(30)" viewBox="-7 160 60 60">
      <animate attributeName="x" from="20%" to="0%" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <polygon points="0,0 0,600 20,600 20,0" fill="green"/>
      <polygon points="20,40 20,600 40,600 40,20" fill="grey"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="url(#skewrect)" fill="none" stroke-width="10"/>
  
</svg>
```

You can also do it with a gradient, or a filter.